# Conditional array assignment in tensorflow compatible with gradient calculation

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

`correct_idx` is a boolean array.

`outp2` is a tensor with same shape as `correct_idx`,

`train_preds` is a tensor. `train_preds` has same shape as number of trues in `correct_idx`

I want to achieve the following equivalent `numpy` result :

```
outp2[correct_idx] = train_preds
```

Can you please suggest something which will also be gradient calculation compatible.

```
correct_idxs2  = tf.convert_to_tensor(correct_idx)
outp2          = tf.where(correct_idxs2, train_preds, tf.constant(float('nan'),dtype=tf.float32))
```

this results in high dimension